# WooCommerce Custom Product Tab: Don't display on certain product pages

Tags: woocommerce

I've got a custom product tab that should appear first (over the Long Description) in my tab lineup. Problem is two of the products should not be seeing this tab at all. So I did a display: none; for that custom tab in CSS for those pages, which worked, but then you see no content in what becomes the first product tab, the long description.

So realistically, that doesn't work. It's just a band aid. So can I add some kind of an if statement to this?

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_tabs', 'woo_new_product_tab1' );
function woo_new_product_tab1( $tabs1 ) {
// Adds the new tab
$tabs1['shade_tab'] = array(
    'title'     => __( 'Product Tab Name', 'woocommerce'     ), 
    'priority'  => 100,
    'callback'  => 'woo_new_product_tab_content1'
);
return $tabs1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the below code, change 11 and 12 to your products ID's

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_tabs', 'woo_new_product_tab1' );
  function woo_new_product_tab1( $tabs1 ) {
    global $product;
      // Adds the new tab
      if( !$product->get_id() == 11 && !$product->get_id() == 12 ){
        $tabs1['shade_tab'] = array(
          'title'     => __( 'Product Tab Name', 'woocommerce' ), 
          'priority'  => 100,
          'callback'  => 'woo_new_product_tab_content1'
        );
      }
    return $tabs1;
}
```

Comment: That worked. The Product Tab Name tab does not appear on those two pages. Unfortunately, it now doesn't appear on any product page.

I tried both && and || since it's really an one or the other, but no luck.

Comment: Make sure you have content in the tab. Also try change condition !$product->get_id() == 11 to $product->get_id() != 11 ..

Comment: Definitely content in the tab. It did show up previously prior to reorganizing the tabs. I’ll try your code change / adjustment shortly. Thank you.

Comment: That change brought us back to square one.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the solution. Ahmad was close but the line should be:
    if( ! in_array( $product->get_id(), array( 232, 280 ) ) ){